# Passing base64 encoded image through form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, resize-crop

I am using an image editing tool for users to upload their images and adjust: http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

I am able to shorten the base64 string by sending it through a couple functions. I am then trying to insert this into a hidden field and submit the form.

```
$('#submit-update-business').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(vanilla.get());
    vanilla.result('canvas', 'viewport', 'png', 0).then(function(src){
        var processed = Base64.encode(JSON.stringify(src));
        $('#new_image').val(processed);
        $('#update-business').submit();
    });
});
```

I know the string is long, but I can't figure out any other way to do this. I've also seen answers that suggest submitting the form through ajax, but this seems to have the same pitfalls. This actually manages to work ok on desktop browsers. It's the mobile ones that have a problem. I can limit the dimensions of the image to less than 3000x3000, but unfortunately phones seem to be taking much higher quality photos.

The tool I'm using, Croppie, has a way to get the data points and zoom, but not the orientation. If there is a way to save this data, or use the base64 data, and re-render the image, and somehow use that image so the image actually goes through, that would be great. If there is a solution I can use just for mobile, that would work too, since it works just fine on desktop.

Comment: Just random thought, if limitation is applied on input field, do chunks, split string into similar chunks and render as many hidden fields as necessary. This will be slow for sure to transfer but other than that should work. Of course if there is a limit of how much data form can send, it's another story. Also sending data via ajax might be a solution as suggested in one of answers.

Comment: I contemplated this. I was considering doing this as a sort of checkbox type of hidden input, so it would be in an array and I could just implode it. But to keep everything simplified, it makes more sense to ajax it over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ajax post instead of submit you don't need a hidden_field if it has length limits in mobile browser. Base64 encoding overhead is not necessary too if you don't need it on a server side.

```
.post(
  "/ajaxpostURL.php",
  {
    new_image: processed, // or new_image: src,
    other_form_param_or_data: 'some_data'
  }
);
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using. I'm sending the image via ajax, reading it, and if it's successful, then submitting the form.